# Take data from next HTML tag

Tags: html, excel, vba

Using this HTML code for example:

```
<table class="table-grid">
<tr>
<th>auto.model</th>
  <td>
    <pre>'Toyota Avensis Wagon'</pre>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<th>auto.year</th>
  <td>
    <pre>2005</pre>
 </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If I take the parameter "auto.model" between `<th></th>` tags and want to receive "Toyota Avensis Wagon", i.e. the next expression between `<pre></pre>`. Ideally I'd like to have function to do it.

Thank you @Jeeped, but code raise "Type mismatch" error and points to `Set el = Param.PreviousSibling`:

    `Sub Extract_TD_text()
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
    Dim Params As IHTMLElementCollection
    Dim Param As HTMLTableCell
    Dim Val As HTMLTableCell
    Dim r As Long
    Dim el As HTMLTableCell
    URL = "My URL"
    Set IE = New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .navigate URL
        .Visible = False
        'Wait for page to load
        While .Busy Or .READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        Set HTMLdoc = .document
    End With
    Set Params = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each Param In Params
    If Param.innerText Like "*auto.model*" Then
        Set el = Param.PreviousSibling
        Exit For
    End If
    Next
    If Not el Is Nothing Then Debug.Print el.innerText
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    End Sub`

Comment: You need to get content in the TR element not the TH's

Comment: Apologies. I mixed up `auto.model` with `auto.year` when I wrote my response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `previousSibling`, I'd like to suggest `nextElementSibling`.

From the way your HTML and VBA codes are currently set up, the current 'param' value being passed should be the `<th>` tag. I think `previousSibling` would likely check the tag that comes before that, and since  is the first element within the `<tr>` (the parent element), there shouldn't be anything (except maybe an invisible node- which `previousSibling` *can* find, but that we don't need).

I *think* `nextElementSibling` should be able to find your `<td>` tag, since it comes after your `<th>` tag.

Comment: Yes! It works!!! Thank you very much. @Looker could write how to create function from this code? I'll be very grateful.

Comment: As it turned out, convert Sub to Function is rather simple: you just need replace `Sub Extract_TD_text()` with `Function Extract_TD_text()`, define variables, at the end write `Extract_TD_text = el.innerText` and replace `End Sub` with `End Function`. Thank you all very much.